# Mapcar and Lambda, an undeclared variable error in LISP

Tags: lambda, common-lisp

I am trying to get the hang of using mapcar and lambda in LISP.  Below, I have a non-working line of code, in which I’m trying to use them.  I get an error, that c is an undeclared free variable.

Where am I going wrong?  Below is the line of code that fails.  Then, my second block is working code, though it is bulkier.

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (c) (member *opponent* (nth c board))) c)

(list (find-empty-position board *corners*)
      "Squeeze Play!  3rd move.")
```

Working code:

```
 (member *opponent*
 (list
  (nth (first *corners*) board)
  (nth (second *corners*) board)
  (nth (third *corners*) board)
  (nth (fourth *corners*) board)))

(list (find-empty-position board *corners*)
      "Squeeze Play!  3rd move.")
```

Comment: The first expression is mapping over the elements of `c`. What's the value of `c`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. The first code calls `member` multiple times, each time on a different element of `board`. The second code calls it once, on a list that contains different elements of `board`.

Comment: I have been staring at my code, but somehow I missed that.

Comment: Then this should work like the 2nd block of code?  

(mapcar #'(lambda (c) (equal *opponent* (nth c board))) *corners*)

Comment: No. `member` returns the list starting with the first matching element. `mapcar` returns a list containing the result of all the function calls, so it will return something like `(nil t nil t)`.

Comment: BTW, put backticks around code in comments, then it won't interpret `*` as markdown.

Comment: What does the call to `find-empty-positions` have to do with any of this?

Comment: It's a function that checks for open positions on a board, then chooses one.  It's for a tic-tac-toe game.

Comment: I understand that. I just wonder why it was necessary to include it in the question, as it seems unrelated to the code you actually have a question about. Is that code part of the function?

Comment: Maybe I should have been more succinct.  I just entered it as a completist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `mapcar` you have to have a list to map over. It looks like you want to iterate over the elements of `*corners*`.

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (c) (member *opponent* (nth c board)))
        *corners*)
```

But to be equivalent to the second code, you shouldn't call `member` inside the loop, it should be called on the result of mapping:

```
(member *opponent*
        (mapcar #'(lambda (c) (nth c board)) *corners*))
```